# Calculating Big O and time complexity of code as a linked list vs array based

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Hi I'm trying to calculate the big O notation of this code, assuming the list that is being used is a linked list

```java
public static void update(List<Star> list) {
// compute and apply acceleration
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Star s1 = list.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        Star s2 = list.get(j);
        Vector acceleration = attractionAcceleration(s1, s2);
        s1.velocity.add(acceleration);
        acceleration.negate();
        s2.velocity.add(acceleration);
    }
}
// apply velocity
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Star s = list.get(i);
    s.location.add(s.velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

I was also asked to calculate the big O assuming the list is an array based list and I got O(N^2) due to it being 2 nested loops. I have been told that the answer for it as a linked list is O(N^4), i'm just not sure how I explain either of these calculations completely

Comment: `list.get(i)` is `O(1)` for an array list and `O(n)` for a linked list. That's the source of the difference in overall runtime

Comment: Who told you the answer for a linked list is O(n^4)? They are wrong, it is O(n^3).

Comment: @kaya3, is that from the velocity loop?

Comment: @MarkHarrison The first part is a nested loop iterating O(n^2) times, where the inner loop does an O(n) `.get`, so the complexity is O(n^3). The second part is a simple loop with O(n) iterations, where each iteration does an O(n) `.get` for a complexity of O(n^2); so the first part dominates the second part.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the linked list, remember that list.get is O(N).  So for the first two lines of your code, you have O(N^2) for lists and O(N) for arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {              O(N) for both
    Star s1 = list.get(i);                           O(N) for list, O(1) for array
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {      O(N) for both
        Star s2 = list.get(j);                       O(N) for list, O(1) for array
    }
}
```

So you have two extra O(N) for lists.  The nested for loops multiply, and `Star s1...` adds, since it is not in the internal loop, giving O(N^3) for the acceleration phase.

Comment: Should be O(n^3); the complexity of `Star s1 = list.get(i);` should be added to the inner loop's complexity, not multiplied by it.